# Store JSON data with setState in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I am straggling with save JSON data to my constructor vars through setState. Is there any way to do it?

**this is my vars:**

```
class House extends Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      Lights_1: "",
      Windows_1: "",
      WantedTemp_1: "",
    };
}
```

**this is my JSON data:**

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "name": "hall1",
    "light_state": 0,
    "window_state": 0,
    "wanted_temp": "20",
    "actual_temp": "20"
  }
]
```

How can I save DATA to vars?

 Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if you are grabbing the json data through a call like axios or something, you can use this with the response!

```
this.setState({
    id: response.ID,
    window_1: response.window_state,

})
```

and so on for the rest of the items that you want to set into state.